# Phpunit Test -Can't find entity (Symfony)

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phpunit

I am new to symfony and phpunit testing and have been getting this error

Cannot stub or mock class or interface "com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Payrollperiod" which does not exist

This is my test which is in the Selenium Test files in the Tests directory.

```
  use com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Mapping\PayPeriodManager;
  use com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Payrollperiod;
  use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
  use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
 class PayrollperiodManagerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase  {public function testPayrollPeriodManager()
{
    $payperiod= $this->createMock(Payrollperiod::class);
    $payperiod->expects($this->once())
              ->method('setstartDate')
              ->will($this->setValue(2011-01-01));
    $payperiod->expects($this->once())
              ->method('setendDate')
              ->will($this->setValue(2011-01-18));
    $payperiod->expects($this->once())
              ->method('setState')
              ->will($this->setValue('Active'));

    var_dump($payperiod);
    die();

   }
   }
```

This is my phpunit.xml.dist

```
   <!-- http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
   <phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
     backupGlobals="false"
     colors="true"
     bootstrap="bootstrap.php.cache"
   >
     <testsuites>
      <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
           <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
          <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>

   <!--
   <php>
    <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
   </php>
    -->

    <filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory>../src</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
               </exclude>
          </whitelist>
         </filter>
      </phpunit>
```

My autoloader

```
  <?php

    use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
    use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

     /**
       * @var ClassLoader $loader
       */
    $loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

    AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

   return $loader;
```

Comment: do you have any `use` statements above your unit test class declaration?

Comment: @ohn-joseph yes please see revised code

Comment: have you tried prefixing them with a backslash? - also, what's your autoloader look like?

Comment: @john-joseph what do you mean by that?

Comment: so `use \com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Payrollperiod;`

Comment: @JohnJoseph still doesn't work :/

Comment: can you post your autoloader? do you have a composer.json file?

Comment: @JohnJoseph autoloader posted yes I do have a composer.json file. Do you need it as well?

Comment: Is `com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Payrollperiod` your class or third party? Where is the file containing this class placed?

Comment: @jakub-matczak  it is my Payrollperiod entity class where I created the getters and setters such as the setstartDate, setendDate and setState

Comment: Where is it located? Do you have suitable autoloader for this path?

Comment: @JakubMatczak it is located in the source directory in a folder with the other entities.